# Python: Tabulating mass spectra fragments of molecules in a publication-ready format

Tags: sorting, printing, rounding, string-formatting

In mass spectrometry (MS), molecules were ionized and broken to fragments (ions) which are deflected by a strong magnetic field according to their mass to charge ratio (*m/z*) and finally detected. The resulting data from the detector is called a mass spectrum which represent the (*m/z*)s of resulting fragments vs. corresponding intensities (Abundances). The example below is the mass spectrum of Toluene (C<sub>7</sub>H<sub>8</sub>). As shown in figure, the most intense ion (*m/z* = 91) is assigned an abundance of 100%, and it is referred to as the base peak:

[image]

In tabulated format, it will be produced as:

```
  m/z, A
  45.47, 8.91
  46.62, 9.21
  ...
  91.27, 100
  93.541, 54.369
```

Where the first column corresponds the fragments *m/z* and the second to the relative abundance; each row is called a **peak**.

In order to properly format this kind of data to a publication-ready table  such as follows:

```
| Analyte | Molecular formula | Molecular weight (Da) | [M]+ *m/z* | MS fragments m/z                                                                                                                                                        |
|---------|-------------------|-----------------------|----------|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Toluene |        C7H8       |         92.14         |    91    | 94 (5), 93 (72), **91 (100)**, 91 (2), 89 (4), 78 (2), 76 (1), 67 (5), 65 (50), 64 (6), 64 (27), 62 (10), 61 (5), 54 (4), 53 (6), 52 (23), 51 (12), 50 (1), 47 (9), 45 (9). |
```

I started to write a script (in Python) which was supposed to do the following:

- Read tabulated mass spectra of many molecules from text files (txt or csv)
- For each file, sort the peaks by decreasing *m/z*
- Round both (*m/z*)s and the relative abundances (*A*) to the nearest integer
- Discard peaks with a weak relative abundance (*A*<1)
- Print the base peak and peaks list according to the example above
- Generate the table in a publication format, as .pdf od .doc

This is my attempt using python pandas library:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import glob, os
from os.path import splitext
os.chdir("/path_to_inupt_file")
import pandas as pd



def print_mzlist(fx):
    # Read peaks table and sort according to *m/z* 
    f = pd.read_csv(fx)
    compname=str(os.path.splitext(fx)[0])
    df = pd.DataFrame(f)
    dfs = df.sort('m_z',ascending=False)


    # Strip peaks with *A* < 1
    dfss = dfs.query('A > 1')

    # Select base peak with A = 100% and add 1 to m/z because the ionization mode is positive
    base_peak=dfs.query('A == 100')+1

    # Create the list of peaks with base_peak as first element
    peaks_list = ""
    bps = str("%s MS1[%0.f]: " %(compname.title(), base_peak['m_z']))
    # Append the Compound name *compname* and *base_peak*
    peaks_list = peaks_list + bps 
    # Append peaks list
    for index, row in dfss.iterrows():
        peaks_list += str ("%.0f (%0.f), " % (row['m_z'], row['A']))
    peaks_list = peaks_list[:-2] + '.'
    return (peaks_list)

# Open the text file to store results
text_file = open("Results.txt", "w")

# Reading csv files and printing the results  
for filename in glob.glob("*.csv"):
    print "Processing the file", filename
    pk= print_mzlist(filename)
    text_file.write("{}\n".format(pk))
    print "Wrinting results to:", text_file.name
text_file.close()
print "Done"
```

Output:

```
Xylene MS1[92]: 107 (6), 106 (66), 105 (29), 104 (3), 103 (6), 102 (1), 92 (8), 91 (100), 89 (2), 79 (7), 78 (6), 77 (12), 74 (1), 65 (6), 63 (5), 62 (2), 53 (3), 52 (3), 51 (9), 50 (4), 41 (1), 39 (8), 38 (1), 27 (4).
Toluene MS1[92]: 94 (5), 93 (72), 91 (100), 91 (2), 89 (4), 78 (2), 76 (1), 67 (5), 65 (50), 64 (6), 64 (27), 62 (10), 61 (5), 54 (4), 53 (6), 52 (23), 51 (12), 50 (1), 47 (9), 45 (9).
Cumene MS1[106]: 121 (3), 120 (27), 106 (9), 105 (100), 104 (3), 103 (7), 102 (1), 91 (6), 79 (12), 78 (6), 77 (14), 65 (2), 63 (2), 53 (1), 52 (3), 51 (9), 50 (3), 41 (3), 39 (6), 28 (1), 27 (4).
Styrene MS1[105]: 105 (9), 104 (100), 103 (41), 102 (6), 89 (2), 79 (2), 78 (35), 77 (17), 76 (4), 75 (2), 74 (3), 65 (1), 63 (5), 62 (2), 52 (7), 51 (17), 50 (7), 39 (6), 38 (1), 27 (3).
```

Source files csv are available in this [github repo](https://github.com/yassineMrabet/MassSpectraPub).

What i need from *stackoverflow* community:

- Revise the code (any suggestions)
- Advise me about a method (or library) to format the results as table and print it as pdf or doc file

Comment: What is the question here? Are you asking us to make the program for you?

Comment: I need only a little help or suggestions on the script (libraries, functions).  I'm working on.

Comment: You don't need any libraries. Just read the file line by line, turn most of the lines of text into a touple of numbers, put them into a list, discard, sort and round the numbers, then print them in the required format